# React JS Google Maps Distance Matrix Error: Uncaught TypeError: locations.join is not a function at formatLocations (index.js:45)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-distancematrix-api

I'm not sure if this is a bug so I'm going to ask for advice first since I'm very new to ReactJS

I'm trying to implement Google Distance Matrix to get the distance.

**(If there are any pre-built reactjs alternative solution, please let me know)**

My Code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import GoogleMap from 'google-distance-matrix';
//...
class View extends Component {
  state = {
    //...
    address:'',
    dest: '',
    distanceText:'',
    openModal: false,
    foundDistance: false,
    distanceText: "",
    address: "New York NY",
    dest: "Montreal"

  };
  constructor (props){
    super(props)
    this.searchUpdated = this.searchUpdated.bind(this);
    this.handleFormSubmit = this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this);

  }

  handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    const component = this
    // const { address, dest } = this.state
    let address = "Toronto, ON, CA"
    let dest = "Vancouver, ON, CA"
    let origins = ['San Francisco CA', '40.7421,-73.9914'];
    let destinations = ['New York NY', 'Montreal', '41.8337329,-87.7321554', 
    'Honolulu'];

    event.preventDefault()
    // console.log(event)
    GoogleMap.matrix(address, dest, function (err, distances) {
        distance.key('AIzaSyCFKLGuYz6ffYby7U-ODjFtV5TO4nDyevE');
        distance.units('imperial');
        console.log("address");
        console.log(dest);
        console.log(err);
        console.log(distances);
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err);
        }
        if(!distances) {
            return console.log('no distances');
        }

        if (distances.status == 'OK') {
            if(distances.rows[0].elements[0])  {
                var distance = distances.rows[0].elements[0].duration['text'];
                console.log(distance);
                component.setState({
                    foundDistance: true,
                    distanceText: distance
                });
            }
        }
    }).bind(this);
}

  componentWillMount() {
    //...
  }
  componentDidMount () {
      // ...
  }
  render() {
//...
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleFormSubmit}>Hello </button>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default View;
```

I literally just want to console.log() the distance between two locations but I'm unable to do so... Right now, it's giving me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: locations.join is not a function
>       at formatLocations (index.js:45)
>   What the error gives me:
>   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is emanating from your `handleFormSubmit` function when you call `GoogleMap.matrix`, it should look like this:

```
  handleFormSubmit = (event) => {
    const component = this
    // const { address, dest } = this.state
    let address = ["Toronto, ON, CA"];
    let dest = ["Vancouver, ON, CA"];

    event.preventDefault()
    // console.log(event)
    GoogleMap.matrix(address, dest, function (err, distances) {
```

Notice the brackets for Toronto and Vancouver; the package expects those two arguments to be arrays, not strings

Comment: Hi, thank you so so much. Now that part is bypassed, I have stumbled with CORS as shown here https://i.gyazo.com/b985db6af53fde2632b6d61b12163b13.png Any luck you can help with this too? (I have given you an upvote for the time being)

Comment: Please note that the package you are using isn't intended for usage in the browser. The CORS issue is known and not considered a flaw: https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js/issues/59#issuecomment-282595007